# How to access dataframe from list of dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

```
employee <- c('John Doe','Peter Gynn','Jolie Hope')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))
employ.data <- data.frame(employee, salary, startdate)
employ.data1<- split(employ.data, rep(1:3, length.out = nrow(employ.data), each = ceiling(nrow(employ.data)/3)))
```

This code helps me obtain a list of 3 seperate dataframes. I am not sure how to access each of these data frames seperately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may need to specify the location of the data frame in the list

```
> employ.data1[[1]]
  employee salary  startdate
1 John Doe  21000 2010-11-01

> employ.data1[[2]]
    employee salary  startdate
2 Peter Gynn  23400 2008-03-25

> employ.data1[[3]]
    employee salary  startdate
3 Jolie Hope  26800 2007-03-14
```